# MathJax: How to change the default color for svg output

Tags: svg, mathjax

I've changed the HTML/CSS color output using

```
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    styles: { ".MathJax": { color: "#fff" } }
  });
```

I've also inverted the png-based output (by inverting every image) with:

```
find ./fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/png -name "*.png" -exec convert {} -negate {} \;
```

Now I'm stuck figuring out the way to fill the SVG glyphs with white instead of the default black. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  styles: {
    ".MathJax_SVG svg > g, .MathJax_SVG_Display svg > g": {
      fill: "#FFF",
      stroke: "#FFF"
    }
  }
});
```

to get the SVG output to be white.

Comment: Will #FFFFFF work the same was as #FFF or can there be some issue?

Comment: That should work fine.  You should be able to set it to any valid color specification.