# How to change default color of SVG in MathJax-Node

Tags: mathjax

I am using [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node) to generate SVGs of equations. I would like to change the default color, but so far nothing has worked.

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366807/2349402) and tried

```
mjAPI.config({MathJax: {
   styles: {
    ".MathJax_SVG, .MathJax_SVG_Display": {
      fill: "#FFF",
      stroke: "#FFF"
    }
  }}});
```

I also tried

```
mjAPI.config({MathJax: {
   SVG: {color: "#0FF", fill: "#0F0", stroke: "#F00"}}});
```

and several variations, like including the `styles` under `SVG`, but so far nothing has worked.

I can work around this by setting the style from within the TeX expression, but I would prefer to be able to set a default configuration so I can process expressions without altering them.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax-node wraps its output in a group with `fill="currentColor stroke="currentColor"` so that it inherits the color from the surrounding text.  So one way to change the color would be to set the color of the container that will hold the SVG output.  The configuration you give above would do that for MathJax in a browser, since MathJax surrounds its SVG output in a container with `class="MathJax_SVG"` or `class="MathJax_SVG_Display"`; but MathJax-node does not produce the container HTML elements that MathJax does, so there are no elements with class `MathJax_SVG` or `MathJax_SVG_Display` being generated.  In any case, the styles are put into a stylesheet that would be added to the page, not used to add explicit styles to the SVG generated, so you would have to include that stylesheet into the page where the SVG output is being put in order for your configuration above to have an effect, even if the containers with the proper classes were being generated.

What you probably want, however, is to have the `currentColor` be some specific color instead, so that there is no inheriting of colors.  Because SVG is a text-based image format, you can do that using a string replacement in your mathjax-node driver file.  For example:

```
mjAPI.typeset({
  math: "x+1",
  format: "TeX",
  svg: true,
  useFontCache: false,
  ex: 6, width: 100
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {
    console.log(data.svg.replace(/"currentColor"/g, '"red"'));
  }
});
```

would set the color to red in the output.

Comment: If I were going to do text replacement on the SVG, I would pipe the output of MathJax-node through `sed` or something, and would just add `color="red"` to the initial SVG element. I would, however, prefer to offer a solution for a command-line option that can be incorporated into MathJax-node via a pull request.

Comment: Yes, setting `color="red"` on the parent SVG element also works.  One could use the `svgNode: true` option rather than `svg: true` to get the SVG node itself (rather than the serialized version of it) and set the color attribute directly, then serialize the result for output (though mathjax-node does a little editing to the output to put in some line breaks and replace the missing `xlink:` namespaces).